# Skip Connection Establishing in Java AWS Lambda Function for calling third party rest APIs

Tags: amazon-web-services, lambda, aws-lambda

I am working on a piece of code in AWS Lambda wriiten in Java which need to call a third party system through REST (fire & forget).

As per this approach, every time a request comes from a user, a new Lambda will be executed which will establish a connection to make a third party call.

Is there any alernate way to overcome connection establishing. Some connection pooling I can make use if I can redirect my calls through API gateway or other connection pool?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

Per the [Lambda documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/running-lambda-code.html):

> After a Lambda function is executed, AWS Lambda maintains the Execution Context for some time in anticipation of another Lambda function invocation
>
> [...]
>
> Any declarations in your Lambda function code (outside the handler code, see Programming Model) remains initialized, providing additional optimization when the function is invoked again. For example, if your Lambda function establishes a database connection, instead of reestablishing the connection, the original connection is used in subsequent invocations.

This is relevant if your Lambda function is invoked repeatedly within a short time frame (I think it's 300 seconds). If it's invoked less frequently then you'll get a new container each time and will need to re-establish your connections.

In the case of a Java implementation, "outside the handler code" includes the object constructor. For example, in [this code](https://github.com/kdgregory/example-lambda-java/blob/master/Webapp-Lambda/src/main/java/com/kdgregory/example/javalambda/webapp/Dispatcher.java#L31) I create a couple of services within the constructor of my Lambda handler class, and store them as member variables.

You could also do lazy instantiation, which I think is more relevant for non-Java implementations (Java gives you constructors, so use them!).

One thing to be aware of is that the underlying connections might time out while the Lambda is inactive. So ensure that you test the connection before use (in the case of a database connection pool this is easy: you give it a "test on checkout" query, and the pool will replace the connection if it's no longer valid).

Comment: Thanks Keith! This looks great. Just for confirmation on my understanding below code will continue to remain in execution context for some time before it discard container due to inactivity. So any heavy resource should bekept as instance variable outside handleRequest() method. Is this correct?
private ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
private UserService userService = new UserService();
private PhotoService photoService = new PhotoService();

Once again thank you for detailed elaboration.

Comment: Correct, keep the expensive resources outside the handler method.

Comment: *"I think it's 300 seconds"*  Historically, this time window has not been officially defined, but testing suggests it's typically several minutes, at least.  Generate a pseudorandom value outside the handler (such as a UUID or high precision timestamp) and log it in each invocation and what you have then is a pseudo-container-id that you can log during each invocation to provide you with a mechanism to visualize container reuse.  Maybe also create a counter variable that you increment with each invocation, and log.

Comment: Yes, I will check with above approach @Michael-sqlbot. However a new problem looks to be a 12MB jar for a normal function whose job is to create a draft user in dynamodb. Looks too heavy!